# I can't access to a single row with Android Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm trying to create an activity that, when you click a button it, shows the detail of a chosen User.
If I try to show (with a text view) the result of a query without parameter (getAllUsers in UserDao) it works. The query with the hardcoded parameter doesnt (the used code will be inserted with a EditText, this is just a test)

Activity

```
findViewById<Button>(R.id.getButton).setOnClickListener() {
            val user = vm.userById(1)
            if(user!= null) {
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.myText).text = user.name
            }
            else {
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.myText).text = "User not found"
            }
        }
```

ViewModel

```
class TestViewModel(private val repo: UserRepository) : ViewModel() {

    fun userById(userId: Int): User? {
        val user =  repo.userById(userId).asLiveData()
        return user.value
    }

    val users: LiveData<List<User>> = repo.users.asLiveData()
}
```

Repository

```
class UserRepository(private val userDao: UserDao) {
    fun userById(userId: Int): Flow<User> {
        return userDao.getUserById(userId)
    }

    val users: Flow<List<User>> = userDao.getAllUsers()
}
```

UserDao

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {

    @Query("SELECT * from user where user_id = :userId")
    fun getUserById(userId: Int): Flow<User>

    @Query("SELECT * from user")
    fun getAllUsers(): Flow<List<User>>
}
```

I searched other guides and tutorials and of course official documentation but I can't understand with the return value is null.

Answer (score 0):

The livedata object returned by the Dao needs to be observed from the activity. In ViewModel, don't return the value from Livedata but return the Livedata itself.

```
fun userById(userId: Int): Livedata<User> {
        return repo.userById(userId).asLiveData()
}

Observe this in the activity.

vm.userById(1).observe(this) { user ->
   // Update textview here
}
```

Comment: the first 3 lines should be in view model and last 3 in activity?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Answer (score 0):

You should set `LIMIT 1` in the `userById` query. Otherwise, it will return a list of all matching users.

```kotlin
@Dao
interface UserDao {

    @Query("SELECT * from user where user_id = :userId LIMIT 1")
    fun getUserById(userId: Int): Flow<User>

}
```

Also, it looks like you are not utilizing the flow directly. I suggest you use a suspend function to return the user instead of returning a flow.

```kotlin
@Dao
interface UserDao {

    @Query("SELECT * from user where user_id = :userId LIMIT 1")
    suspend fun getUserById(userId: Int): User?

}
```

Comment: You should clarify that `LIMIT 1` is needed _if multiple users can have the same ID_, which is unlikely to be the case ("ids" are usually a unique, primary key that identifies a single entity)